# How App developer and App installer can interact

Tags: android

I am developing a App in which I want to send update of my App by notification to all user who have install my App. 
But problem is that How I will interact with user who have install my App?

I know that by

```
      TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
       System.out.println("Phone number"+mPhoneNumber);
       Toast.makeText(Splashscreen.this, "Phone No." +""+mPhoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

above code we can import Phone number, but this above code will not work for Android 2.3 ,4.1,4.2.

I need some sure and reliable medium through which I and all user who has install my App can interact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate C2DM in your application.

Comment: C2DM is past it is now GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)